# How to get a random value in the Robot Inventor software (Python)

Tags: programming, spike-prime, robot-inventor, micropython

I am making a Python program with the LEGO Robot Inventor software which will, among other things, turn the robot a random amount periodically, which of course requires a random number. However, I could not find any way to do so. Is there any Python function which I could use to get a random number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Python has this built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). Or is there some reason you can't use it?

Comment: Thanks! I had simply not known about that function.

Comment: Not every function from full python is necessarily available in every partial (or micro) python implementation, so I wanted to check first before going down a more elaborate route.

Comment: Links tend to break. Could you give a code example in your answer in case the link is no longer available?

Comment: I'm guessing python.org is pretty safe.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for a concrete example using (Micro)Python's `random`, I created a small program that randomly displays images in the hub. You can find it here https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/arturomoncadatorres/lego-mindstorms/blob/main/examples/programs/random_images.ipynb?flush_cache=True

Answer (score 5):

Under operators, there is a block "Pick Random" where you can specify to pick an integral number between x to y... x and y you can type... So for a random direction, set it between 0 and 359 degrees ...

[image]

Comment: I am actually using python, so this solution is not really applicable, but that's my fault for not saying so.